# How do I enable implementation of DiscoveryServices in Milo for LDS?

Tags: opc-ua, milo

I implemented the DiscoveryServiceSet interface from Milo and I already have a demo UA Server implemented using the Milo SDK. I would like to create an LDS Server by adding the DiscoveryServices which I have implemented. How do I enable this? I looked in OpcUaServer.class and the constructor adds all the services. However, it uses the this.sessionManager which I am not able to access or modify the constructor. In addition, I also saw that UaStackServer.class also has the AddServiceSet methods built in. Do I have to use one of those methods to enable my DiscoveryServices? If so, the constructor for UaStackServer already has added the DefaultDiscoveryService using those methods. How can I override it to use my implementation?